# reference to parent class in Lua (Corona)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

in my game.lua file I have this:

```
function new()

    local obj = display.newGroup();

    currentLevel = Level.new(1);
    currentLevel.game = obj; //also tried currentLevel.game = self;

    function obj:replay()
            print("game - replay")
    end

    return obj;

end
```

In the Level lua file, I try to call the replay function in game.lua:

```
game = {};
...
game:replay();
```

But I get this error:
attempt to call method 'replay' (a nil value)

How can I keep a reference to the game file in level.lua?

Answer (score 7):

Don't you mean `game = new()`, instead of `game = {}`? If you create `game` with `{}` then it is an empty table.

Comment: @clua7, It is a good custom to mark a correct answer so the person who helped you gets the credit for it.